# Deriving a formula to find the sum of a series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have attempted to solve this problem:

Find the sum of the series, if it converges.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^{n-1}}{7^n}$

I see that the values of $a_n$ are $\frac{1}{7} + \frac{-2}{49} + \frac{4}{343} + \frac{-8}{2401} + ...$

And that the values of $s_n$ are $\frac{1}{7},\frac{5}{49},\frac{39}{343},\frac{265}{2401},...$

I am trying to derive a formula for $s_n$ but feel stuck. I know the denominator of this mystery equation is $7^n$, but I can't seem to figure out what the rest of the equation would be. An explanation/corrections to my method would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^{n-1}}{7^n}=-\frac12\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^n}{7^n}=-\frac12\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-\frac27\right)^n$$

Now see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Inafinite_geometric_series)

Comment: I'm trying really hard to see and understand how you went from the first part of that equation to the second. I also considered turning that ^(n-1) into simply an ^(n) but did not know how to do that. I see that you are to multiply it by -1/2 in order to do so but how does that relationship make sense? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @RogerVillanueva, What is the general term of a Geometric Series?

Comment: @RogerVillanueva Simple exponent arithmetic reads $a^{n-1} = a^n a^{-1} = \frac{a^n}{a}$.  In your case this says $(-2)^{n-1} = \frac{1}{-2} (-2)^n$.