# To check convergence\divergence of infinite series $\frac 1{2^1} +\frac{1}{3^2}+ \frac 1{2^3} +\frac 1{3^4}\ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Series is as follows :

$$\frac 1{2^1} +\frac{1}{3^2}+ \frac 1{2^3} +\frac 1{3^4}\ldots$$
Thanks in advance

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006168/deriving-a-formula-to-find-the-sum-of-a-series

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

The series can be rewritten as $$\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac1{2^{2r+1}}+\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac1{3^{2r}}$$

$$=\frac12\sum_{r=0}^\infty\left(\frac14\right)^r+\sum_{r=1}^\infty\left(\frac19\right)^r$$